# AVG of the last 7 days not returning results

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have an expression to give me the AVG of `TIMETAKEN` in the last 7 days but it isn't returning any results.

```
=AVG({<STARTDATE={"<$(=date(today()-7))"} >}TIMETAKEN)
```

I can get yesterdays AVG with this and it works:

```
=AVG({<STARTDATE={"$(=Date(Today()-1))"}>} TIMETAKEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
count({<Date={"=Date>(today()-7)"}>}[Date])
```

Extra credit for

```
count({<Date={"=Date<(today())"}*{"=Date>(today()-7)"}>}[Date])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the following expression to achieve this:

```
=AVG({<STARTDATE=
{"$(=Date(Today()-7))","$(=Date(Today()-6))","$(=Date(Today()-5))",
"$(=Date(Today()-4))","$(=Date(Today()-3))","$(=Date(Today()-2))",
"$(=Date(Today()-1))"}>}TIMETAKEN)
```